# How do I get the probability value of a "detected" object?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

inp is an image.

```
 prediction = model.predict([inp])
```

I have trained it with cats and dogs respectively.

```
    if int(prediction[0][0]) == 0:
        print("it is a cat")
```

How do I know probabilities of cat or dog for this input?

Comment: What kind of output have in your model? Softmax? Or sigmoid?

Comment: @AdriaCiurana sigmoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have a discriminator between dog and cat. Understanding that you have labeled the data 0 as a cat and 1 as a dog.

The output then represents a binary event when is near to zero is cat and when is near to 1 is dog. p(dog) = prediction and p(cat) = 1 - p(dog).

A study called **ROC-curve** or **PR-curve** is usually done to determine at what point to discriminate between cat and dog.

But in your case to go fast you can consider 0.5, that is:

```
p = model.predict([inp]) 
is_cat = p <= 0.5
is_dog = p> 0.5
```